# How to send a bitmap to a java socket server?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am sending an image from android client to a java server socket. Presently i am using the following code -

Client Code

```
try
            {
                if (bmp != null & socket!=null)
                {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,stream);
                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    InputStream inn = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
                    dos.writeInt(byteArray.length);
                    int len = 0 ;
                    byte [] b = new byte [1024];
                    while ((len = inn.read(b)) != -1)
                    {
                        dos.write(b,0,len);
                    }
                    dos.flush();
                    stream.close();
                    inn.close();
                    result = in.readLine();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                Log.d("Exception Caught", ioe.getMessage());
            }
```

Server Code

```
try
                {
                    int length = in.readInt();
                    System.out.println("Got the Size");
                    int bytesRead ;
                    int len = 0;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    while (len<length)
                    {
                        bytesRead = in.read(buffer,0,(int)Math.min(buffer.length, length-len));
                        len = len + bytesRead;
                        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    byte [] byteArray = new byte [length];
                    byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
                    File file = new File (fileName+(int)(Math.random()*500)+".jpg");
                    if (!file.exists())
                    {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream (file);
                    fos.write(byteArray);
                    fos.close();
                    out.println("Image Received");
                }
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
```

However i have create two extra streams on the client side just to determine and send the size of the image compressed to JPEG format instead of using the `bmp.compress()` directly on the socket output stream. So i wanted to know if it was possible to prevent the overhead of the two extra streams in the client code or is there some other approach which will have lesser overhead ?

Comment: You don't need to call `createNewFile()` before `new FileOutputStream(...)`. It just wastes time and space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to keep the connection open, don't send the length and just read to end of stream. If you do need to keep it open, your copy loop isn't correct: it can overrun at the end of the image. It should be:

```
while (len<length)
{
    bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, length-len));
    len = len + bytesRead;
    baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: I need to keep the connection open, so have modified the copy loop. Any other optimisations to speed up the whole process ?

Comment: The thing to do is get it working first,but in any case you can't speed it up beyond the speed of the network. This is as good as it gets.